# How can i show an image from its pixels which are already saved in a file ?

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, vision

I m using opencv and c++ to save an image's pixels in a file, now i want to restore the image in order to show it again. could you give some suggestions?

[update: included code from OP's comments]
I'm using these loops to save my image's pixels in a file

```
for(int row=0; row<a;row++) 
    for(int col=0;col<b;col++) { 
        pixel[row][col]= ((uchar *)(img->imageData + row*img->widthStep))[col*img->nChannels +0];
```

Now i m trying to read these pixel in order to show the image

Comment: Do the exact opposite, but in reverse?

Comment: i m using these loops to save my image's pixels in a file, for(int row=0; row<a;row++) 
    for(int col=0;col<b;col++)
       {

pixel[row][col]= ((uchar *)(img->imageData + row*img->widthStep))[col*img->nChannels +0]; now i m trying to read these pixel in order to show the image .

Comment: @AbdelazizOudouch: Edit this post to show your code, don't put your code in a comment.  Can you easily read the code **YOU** put in the comment?

Comment: you ae talking about a file,butyou dont read a file in your code. what represent img,what does it contain ? for respect to readers, write correctly what contains exactly the img structure. and what you want to fill. my response : simply fill img->imageData with pixel[][]... ? then i suppose you writethe content to a file.

Answer (score 2):

The standard (recommended) way to store image data in the disk is putting the pixels in an image container (jpg/png/bmp/tiff/...) and save that to a file. OpenCV handles this process very easily, since you already have `img` as `IplImage*` all you need to do is call [`cvSaveImage()`](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/c/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#saveimage) and give the name of the file:

```
if (!cvSaveImage("output.png", img))
{
    // print cvSaveImage failed and deal with error
}
```

then, to read this file from the disk use can use [`cvLoadImage()`](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/c/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#loadimage), which you have probably used already.

If, for some mysteryous reason you are actually storing just the pixels in a file it would be perfectly understandable that you want to read them back to an `IplImage` structure. For this purpose, the function you are looking for is [`cvCreateImage()`](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/c/core_operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=cvcreateimage#cvCreateImage):

```
IplImage* new_img = cvCreateImage(cvSize(width, height), /*img depth*/, /* nChannels*/);
```

after creating `new_image` you need to `mempcy()` the pixels read to `new_image->imageData`.

**However**, you need to know beforehand what's the actual size of the image to be able to use this approach. If you are just storing the pixels of the image inside the file then I suggest you store the size of the image as a part of the filename.

One benefit from using OpenCV functions to deal with images is that your system will be able to recognize and display them (which is so important for debugging purposes).

Answer (score 0):

```
img->imageData = malloc(a*img->widthStep);  //do this if you didnt allocate the memory before. a*img->widthStep shouldbe the right size of memor needed if imn ot wrong.   
for(int row=0; row<a;row++) 
{
     for(int col=0;col<b;col++) 
     { 
  ((uchar*)(img->imageData + row*img->widthStep))[col*img->nChannels +0] = pixel[row][col];
   // you didnt say what is th type of date in imadeData : put other casts if necessary.
        }
    }
```

do you take all the information in img->imageData and put it in pixel in your original code ?

so, the answer of karlphillip : " you need to mempcy() the pixels read to new_image->imageData" is what i did in my code.

Comment: I m handling only images in Gray scale. ( i m sorry for my bad quality in communication, but i m sure i ll improve my level , in order toparticipate actively in this website )